# How to solve "The network connection was lost" error it occured when used ModernHttpClient in Xamarin.Forms iOS project?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, httpclient

I have a mobile application that I developed with Xamarin Forms. I also have an internal web application that hosts API methods for my mobile application requests.

I want to request these API methods through my mobile application. However, since my web application is internal, I need to access API methods in the web application via a tunnel.

In order to do this, I integrated Airwatch SDK into my mobile application at the request of our customer. (I only do this on the iOS part of my Xamarin.Forms project.) When I looked at the Airwatch SDK AppTunnel documentation, I saw that I needed to use ModernHttpClient in all HttpClient requests for AppTunnel and I made these changes. I am currently accessing the internal API methods using the AppTunnel feature of the Airwatch SDK.
(AppTunnel with Airwatch SDK: https://developer.vmware.com/web/workspace-one/tutorials/Xamarin-iOS/App-Tunneling/Airwatch-SDK)

I also have a "Multipart/Form-Data POST" api method that I use for file upload in application. I've changed this to work with ModernHttpClient as well. Uploading small files also worked without a problem. However, I am getting the following error while uploading a large file.

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The network connection was lost.) ---> System.Net.WebException: The network connection was lost. ---> Foundation.NSErrorException: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=54, NSUnderlyingError=0x28370d980 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=54, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask .<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(\n    "LocalDataTask .<1>"\n), NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://base-url.com/api/v2/filesystem/upload, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://base-url.com.com/api/v2/filesystem/upload, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\n  at ModernHttpClient.NativeMessageHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x1088d8130 + 0x01143> in <67401bece23c4316a0cb1acd7b396157#0821ad7e7f240e13aa5b8f0971c62be4>:0 \n  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) <0x1073d7a80 + 0x005f4> in <992c809de76342e0b46dc1b912da2d7b#0821ad7e7f240e13aa5b8f0971c62be4>:0 \n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\n  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) <0x10490f1a0 + 0x00048> in <aae03b95719e488f8a163bae4d2b5dcb#0821ad7e7f240e13aa5b8f0971c62be4>:0 \n  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].GetResultCore (System.Boolean waitCompletionNotification) <0x10490a080 + 0x00097> in <aae03b95719e488f8a163bae4d2b5dcb#0821ad7e7f240e13aa5b8f0971c62be4>:0 \n  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].get_Result () <0x104909fe0 + 0x00067> in <aae03b95719e488f8a163bae4d2b5dcb#0821ad7e7f240e13aa5b8f0971c62be4>:0 \n  at AppSDK.V2.Service.Uploader.SendStreamToServer (System.String fileName, System.IO.Stream stream, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection nvc) <0x107cd73b0 + 0x00633> in <d8bc2b7aa0fc423f94af434e3edd0df7#0821ad7e7f240e13aa5b8f0971c62be4>:0 \n---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.WebException: The network connection was lost. ---> Foundation.NSErrorException: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 \"The network connection was lost.\" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=54, NSUnderlyingError=0x28370d980 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 \"(null)\" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=54, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <F5B801BE-A8A1-4EBC-89D2-EA1D79B4C72B>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(\n    \"LocalDataTask <F5B801BE-A8A1-4EBC-89D2-EA1D79B4C72B>.<1>\"\n), NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://base-url.com.com/api/v2/filesystem/upload, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://base-url.com.com/api/v2/filesystem/upload, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\n  at ModernHttpClient.NativeMessageHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x1088d8130 + 0x01143> in <67401bece23c4316a0cb1acd7b396157#0821ad7e7f240e13aa5b8f0971c62be4>:0 \n  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) <0x1073d7a80 + 0x005f4> in <992c809de76342e0b46dc1b912da2d7b#0821ad7e7f240e13aa5b8f0971c62be4>:0 <---\n

I tried the followings to resolve this error.

1. Uploading a large file by dividing it into smaller parts (for example, trying to upload an 850 mb file in 500 kb chunks. In this case, for example, 60-70 mb of the file is uploaded, then suddenly I get the above error.)
2. I increased the timeout of the HttpClient object.

```
_client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
```

3. I increased the timeout of ModernHttpClient.

```
NativeMessageHandler handler = new NativeMessageHandler() 
{ 
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20) 
};
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

4. I added "Connection: Close" to the header of the http request.

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Close");
```

or

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
```

or

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;
```

5. I added "Connection: Keep-Alive" to the header of the http request and increased the Keep-Alive timeout (for example: "Keep-Alive: 180000")

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Keep-Alive", "180000");
```

6. I tried the above items separately using modernHttpClient and modernhttpclient-updated.

(ModernHttpClient: https://github.com/anaisbetts/ModernHttpClient)

(modernhttpclient-updated: https://github.com/alexrainman/ModernHttpClient)

However, none of them worked.

I saw this issue: https://github.com/anaisbetts/ModernHttpClient/issues/204

It says there is a problem with the server. But I don't understand how I need to make a setting on the server to fix this.

What can I do to fix this problem I'm facing while uploading high size files?

Comment: Don't use ModernHttpClient. Just use regular AndroidMessageHandler instead. ModernHttpClient is a dead library and has been like that for over 5 years, why keep using something broken?

Comment: Because I'm trying to integrate Airwatch SDK's App Tunneling feature into my project, and in the Airwatch SDK Xamarin.iOS documentation it says ModernHttpClient must be used in http requests to integrate App Tunneling. (I actually stated that in my question)
Also I'm trying to integrate this on iOS not android and I tried using NSUrlSessionHandler for iOS. But if I use this I can't App Tunneling. Therefore I have to use ModernHttpClient to integrate this feature.